# How to store pointer to abstract class into priority queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have 3 classes :

- `Event` wich is purely abstract
- `Arrive` wich derivate from event
- `Leave` wich also derivate from event

`Event` is defined as follow :

```cpp
class Event{
protected:
    double time;
}
```

I need to store events into a queue and retrieve them in ascending order based on event time.

To do that I created a priority_queue like this :

```cpp
priority_queue<Event*, vector<Event*>, greater<>>
```

Comparators have been defined for `Event` based on time.

I push into this queue objects of type `Arrive` and `Leave`.

Everything works great except that the queue return object not based on the smallest time but on the smallest pointer address value.

Comment: Please read [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @CuriousLearner The queue compares pointers Event *. You have to write you own comparator using for example a lambda expression. Instead it seems you defined the comparison for objects of the type Event but the comparator is not used by the queue.

Comment: @CuriousLearner The linked duplicate contains lots of example `Compare` implementations. All you have to do is implement `operator()(const Node*, const Node*)` instead of `operator()(Node, Node)`.

Comment: Thanks to all your answers !
I solved the problem using a multiset instead and by defining a class with `operator()(const Event*, const Event*)`.